# Dereferencing null pointer

Tags: c++, dereference

I am trying to write a very simple pointer assignment in C++ like this:

```
float  *src;
if(someCondition == true)
    src = somePointer;
else
    src = someOtherPointer;
```

However, when I try to access src, I get a warning saying "Dereference of null pointer( loaded from variable src)"

Also, if I try to give some initial value to src like this:

```
float  *src = aPointer;

if(someCondition == true)
    src = somePointer;
else
    src = someOtherPointer;
```

I get a warning saying that the initial value assigned to src is never read. Even though this doesnt seem to be affecting what I am trying to do, I am trying to get rid of all potential issues. What seems to be the problem here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `someCondition`?

Comment: What are `somePointer` and `someOtherPointer`?

Comment: Show us how `somePointer` and `someOtherPointer` are established please.

Comment: float * src = someCondition ? somePointer : someOtherPointer;

Comment: if(variableX > 350) src = &(anArray[0]) else src = &(anArray[50]). Thats the gist of the condition that I am trying to implement. Thanks!

Comment: The `== true`, though legal, is a bad idea. It's already a condition, so just write `if (someCondition)`. Apart from the unnecessary verbosity, if `someCondition` isn't of type `bool`, it could have a "true" (i.e., non-zero) value other than 1.

Comment: `somePointer` and `someOtherPointer` seem to be null pointers. is it so?

Comment: Do you get the warning from the compiler or when you run the program? As for the "src is never read" warning, that's because you don't use the value of `src` after assigning to it. Obviously your program is incomplete; the warning should go away when you add code to use `src`.

Comment: You do not show enough information at all. Is your src variable global? Where and how do you use it?

Comment: @KeithThompson: dereferencing null pointer would not be warning at runtime.

Comment: I get this error when I do a static analysis. Also, all the variables are local to the scope that I am working in (inside one method). The other two pointers are definitely not null. And although I appreciate the advice, I was just trying to simplify the situation when posting here. Maybe I overdid it!

Comment: @user1664101 can we see the declaration and initialization of `anArray`?

Answer (score 3):

Since your using pointer and not reference expect `NULL` to be a possible value of your pointers.

It might be in your interest to check for NULL:

```
if(!src) {/*handle null case*/}
```

Comment: 'always' is a bit strong. A program can establish and maintain non-null invariants and therefore avoid having to always check for null.

Answer (score 2):

presumably one or both of `somePointer` and `someOtherPointer` are 0/NULL

Comment: No, i know for a fact that they are valid pointers. I am using them elsewhere too. Also, even though this is potentially unsafe because of the warning that I get, this piece of code is working just fine. It wouldn't work if any of the two pointers were NULL/0. I am just trying to get rid of the warning and the possibly unsafe situation.

Comment: it sounds to me like the compiler is seeing something you don't see.  it might be some unexpected execution path, try to check them all.  narrow in on the problem by commenting out blocks of code to see if/when the warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that `src` will always be initialized. Although IDK why it would assume that the poiter would be NULL, more likely it would be some garbage value. This can probably be fixed by making the initialization a single statement using the ternary operator (?:) :

```
float* src = someCondition ? somePointer : someOtherPointer;
```

EDIT:

Try initializing `src` to NULL. That should get rid of the initialization warnings and I doubt that it will create an unused value warning.

Comment: I did try that, but it still gives the same warning. Inspite of the tertiary operator, the compiler doesnt realize that the  pointer has been initialized. :(

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help either.